# @MessageLogger and @MessageBundle

Tags: jboss-logging

I use jboss-logging. According to https://jboss-logging.github.io/jboss-logging-tools/#message-bundle-interfaces, there the two types:

- @MessageLogger for log messages
- @MessageBundle for exceptions and string messages

I don't know how this is internally handled but using

```
@MessageLogger(projectCode = "TESTLOGGER", length = 3)
public interface TestLogger {

    // This is not a log message, but a string message
    @Message(id=1, value = "invalid {0}", format = Message.Format.MESSAGE_FORMAT)
    void test(String dateString);
    
    // this is a typical log message
    @LogMessage
    @Message(id=2, value = "invalid {0}", format = Message.Format.MESSAGE_FORMAT)
    void test(String dateString);

    // this is a typcial exception 
    @Message(id = 3, value = "Invalid '%s'")
    IllegalArgumentException invalidPermissionAction(String action);
}

}
```

also works. So I assume that I can put log messages, exceptions and string messages within a `@MessageLogger` and don't need to separate them by `@MessageBundle`. Am I right? Are there any hidden limitations with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. You can put log messages, string messages and exceptions in the same file.